# Postgres jsonb to table

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to return jsonb array of arrays as a table object?
The size of the inner arrays will **not** always be the same.
Postgres version 9.6.6 is being used.

Example jsonb:

```
{
    "r": [
        {
            "n": "name",
            "rcs": [
                [
                    {
                        "v": "1",
                        "vt": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "2",
                        "vt": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "3",
                        "vt": 9
                    }                   
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "v": "4",
                        "vt": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "5",
                        "vt": 7
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected table

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3   |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    2 |    3   |
|    4 |    5 |  Null  |
+------+------+--------+
```

The width of the returned table will be determined by the max length of all rows.
Excess columns for shorter rows will have null values.

I am completely new to Postgres, and not even sure where to start.
This was as far as I got:

```
select c from someTable,
jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'r') r,
jsonb_array_elements(r -> 'rcs') c
WHERE  r->> 'n' = 'name'
```

Comment: You can't have a table object with an indeterminate number of columns.  Your example output just kind of glosses over this with an ellipsis, but that doesn't work.  We need to see what you actually want to happen.

Comment: A good place to start is with valid examples.  Your JSONB object is not valid (the outer [] should be {}, I suspect) and you can't have a table named `table`, unless you include double quotes around it when you use it (`"table"` but please don't do that, just pick a different name)

Comment: The width of the table will be determined by the max length of the inner arrays.
The name table is for example purposes only. There are other elements and arrays that I left out of the real jsonb for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Postgres version not disclosed, invalid example. Please improve your question.

Comment: Postgres version 9.6.6 is being used.

Comment: "*The width of the returned table will be determined by the max length of all rows*" - this is not possible. A row of a table must always have a fixed amount of columns, and the columns have to be known to be able to query them. The closest you would get is something like [`json_to_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html), but even there the documentation states: "*As with all functions returning `record`, the caller must explicitly define the structure of the record with an `AS` clause.*".

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, this is a pretty definitive answer.